# Raspbian-NOOBS Install slow

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, noobs

**System Specifications**:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- SanDisk Ultra 16GB Micro SD Class 10
- NOOBS 2.4.4 - Raspbian

I have formatted the SD card as FAT32 and copied the OS contents onto the SD card. Once I plugged into the Pi and powered it on, I selected Raspbian.
It has started the Installation process, but it is very slow.

```
Raspbian: Downloading and Extracting Filesystem
4MB of 4104MB wriiten (0.0MB/s)  
Progress: 0%
```

Red Light is constant. Green Light blinks. No Low Power Indicator(Thunderbolt/Lightning symbol).

It is installing at **0.0MB/s**.
Even with a fast SD card, the installation time is very slow. It has taken more than 20mins to install 4/4104MB. I have tried several times,  to restart the installation by reformatting and copying its contents, but to no avail.

In the past, I have used the same OS files, SD Card & RasPi and it has installed the OS way faster. I changed the SD card too, but still no luck.

What could be the problem & How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was most likely caused because the OP used NOOBS Lite. He probably downloaded it because of the much smaller filesize, and either didn't know the difference or forgot to mention it. NOOBS 2.4.4 came with Raspbian, and LibreELEC downloaded along with NOOBS, hence the larger filesize.

```
Raspbian: Downloading and Extracting Filesystem
4MB of 4104MB wriiten (0.0MB/s)  
Progress: 0%
```

This is from NOOBS Lite, which connects to the internet and downloads the OS to the Pi once you select it. NOOBS doesn't even ask you to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, however the problem seems to be a network/internet bottleneck based on the information provided by the OP:

`Raspbian: Downloading and Extracting Filesystem`

*"In the past, I have used the same OS files, SD Card & RasPi and it has installed the OS way faster. I changed the SD card too, but still no luck."*

Beyond that guess it's unlikely the true source can be narrowed down without more information; e.g. Downloading over WiFi/Ethernet, other network devices are/aren't operating normally, tried changing connections, etc.

Comment: A 0.34 mbps connection is normal if you're using a wifi network with a low-end plan. There could also be another person using the network.